# Crash with Xcode 9 when mocking a NSManagedObject

Tags: xcode, stack-overflow, nsmanagedobject, ocmock

Since downloading XCode 9, some of my unit tests have started to crash with a stack overflow (try searching for *that* these days!).

The problems seem to come from trying to create an `OCMock` of an `NSManagedObject` subclass, such as this line: `OCMClassMock([User class])`, where `User` is an `NSManagedObject` subclass.

There's a [bug and discussion](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues/339) about this in the OCMock git repo.

The discussion mentions that OCMock supports mocking of NSManagedObject subclasses since [version 3.4](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/v3.4/Source/Changes.txt#L7).

Any suggestions for fixing this or working around it? I guess it will probably need a fix to OCMock, but maybe there's an XCode setting that could be tweaked, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just added a (preliminary) workaround to OCMock. Pease see the Github issue you linked to for details.